# Display image on right side of header text in XamMenu in silverlight page

Tags: silverlight-4.0, infragistics, xamgrid

I have created a XamMenu in my silverlight page. It consists of 4 options in it. The header for the first item is 'order'. I am using xamMenuItem.icon to add an image on the right side of the header text. But it is always coming on the left side of the header text. How can I do that? Please help.

My xaml code id like this:

```
<ig:XamMenu x:Name="xamOrderMenu" Height="22" Width="120" ExpandOnHover="True" Canvas.Left="361" Canvas.Top="10">
                   <ig:XamMenuItem Header="Order" SubmenuPreferredLocation="Bottom"  Background="LightGray" FontWeight="Bold" Cursor="Hand">      
                        <ig:XamMenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Source="/Asset.View;component/Images/downarrow.PNG"/>
                        </ig:XamMenuItem.Icon>
                        <ig:XamMenuItem Header="Order1" StaysOpenOnClick="True" Background="LightGray" Click="ExportToExcel_Click" Cursor="Hand"/>
                        <ig:XamMenuItem Header="Order2" Background="LightGray" Click="DownloadFundCountTemplate_Click" Cursor="Hand"/>
                        <ig:XamMenuItem Header="Order3" Background="LightGray" Click="UploadTemplate_Click" Cursor="Hand"/>
                        <ig:XamMenuItem Header="Order4" Background="LightGray" Click="SearchAndExportToExcel_Click" Cursor="Hand"/>
                    </ig:XamMenuItem>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to retemplate the XamMenuItem to place the icon in a different spot.  In the default template, the XamMenuItem is seperated into 3 columns.  The icon is placed into the left-most column, header text in the center and the child indicator in the right-most column.

If you have the Infragistics product installed you have access to the default template.  You can find it here:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Infragistics\NetAdvantage (release version #)\Silverlight\DefaultStyles\XamMenu

Open the generic.xaml file and do a search for XamMenuItem and the first thing that comes up should be the style for it.  The template can be found there.  Add this style and its dependencies to your project and then make the necessary adjustments to place the icon on the right side of the header text.  You can then assign this style to your XamMenuItems.